# Что такое "одноадресная система команд" в ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер, терминология, системное-программирование

Что такое "одноадресная система команд" в ассемблере и чем она отличается от двухадресной?

Comment: https://www.ngpedia.ru/id430178p1.html

Comment: В одноадресных командах кодируется адрес только одного операнда, если требуется второй, то он существует неявно (например, аккумулятор для сложения или счетчик команд (instriction counter) для команд перехода) и определяется кодом команды. В двухадресных командах кодируются 2 операнда (ну, также может быть неявный третий). Вообще можете почитать http://educomp.runnet.ru/theory/ustr/1_6.html